# Adafruit Ultimate GPS sendCommand

Tags: microcontroller, c, stm32f4, gps

EDIT: Solved, Problem was with not sending "\r\n" at the end of the sentence.

I'm trying to control Adafruit Ultimate GPS through STM32F407, there is an official Arduino [Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_GPS/blob/master/Adafruit_GPS.cpp) and this library has a **sendCommand()** function. I'm trying to implement this sendCommand() function in Keil using HAL library

```
// arduino command for setting antenna off
GPS.sendCommand("$PGCMD,33,0*6D\n");
```

In keil I wrote these lines

```
uint8_t Tx_Buffer[100];
int size;

// Turn off antenna update nuisance data
size = sprintf(Tx_Buffer,"$PGCMD,33,0*6D\n");
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, Tx_Buffer, size, 100);
HAL_Delay(100);

// Set the update speed
size = sprintf(Tx_Buffer,"$PMTK220,500*2B\n");
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, Tx_Buffer, size, 100);
HAL_Delay(100);

// Request RMC and GGA sentences only
size = sprintf(Tx_Buffer,"$PMTK314,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0*28\n");    
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, Tx_Buffer ,size, 100);
HAL_Delay(1000);
```

However, it seems that I am not changing anyting because it is still giving data in defaults settings. UART Baudrate is 9600 (Transmit and receive)

Can you help me with the C code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a '\n' on the end of your 'Set the update speed' command.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it before, just missed it at last run. In addition I tried running it with "\n\r" too.

Comment: @ZiyaKeskin “\n\r” would be very uncommon. Typically either “\n” or “\r\n”.

Comment: I just tried it with "\r\n", and it is working. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Please post an answer containing exactly that information, @ZiyaKeskin. It will allow us to recognize this question as answered, and will thus help others more, and as a bonus, you can earn more reputation points that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with not sending "\r\n" at the end of the sentence.